# Incorrect header check zlib

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

Running the code below to to download and unzip files. It works as intended when I try with one but when I do multiple at the same time I get the following error:

> Error: incorrect header check at Zlib._handle.onerror

```
var downloadUnzipFile = function (mID) {
      try {
        // Read File    
        console.log("Started download/unzip of merchant: " + mID + " @ " + new Date().format('H:i:s').toString());
        request(linkConst(mID))
          // Un-Gzip
          .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
          // Write File
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName(mID)))
          .on('error', function (err) {
            console.error(err);
          })
          .on('finish', function() {
            console.log("CSV created: " + fileName(mID));
            console.log("Completed merchant: " + mID + " @ " + new Date().format('H:i:s').toString());
            //console.log("Parsing CSV...");
            //csvReader(fileName);
          });

      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }


    module.exports = function(sMerchants) {
      var oMerchants = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sMerchants));
      oMerchants.forEach(function eachMerchant(merchant) {
        downloadUnzipFile(merchant.merchant_aw_id);
      })
    };
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks

EDIT:

To clarify, i'd like to run through each item (merchant) in the array (merchants) and download a file + unzip it. The way I currently do it means it this downloading/zipping occurs at the sametime (which I think might be causing the error). When i remove the foreach loop and just try to download/zip one merchant the code works.

Comment: "One", "multiple" - you mean, one file at a time versus some files in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as you suggest, it's likely that if you try to unzip too many files concurrently, you will run out of memory.  Because you are handling streams, the unzip operations are asynchronous, meaning your `forEach` loop will continue to be called before each unzip operation completes.  There are plenty of node packages that allow you to handle async operations so you can run the unzip function sequentially, but the simplest approach might just be to use a recursive function call.  E.g.:

```
var downloadUnzipFile = function (mID) {
  try {
    // Read File    
    console.log("Started download/unzip of merchant: " + mID + " @ " + new Date().format('H:i:s').toString());
    return request(linkConst(mID))
      // Un-Gzip
      .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
      // Write File
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName(mID)))
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return false;
  }
}


module.exports = function(sMerchants) {
  var merchants = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sMerchants)),
      count = 0;

  downloadUnzipFile(merchants[count][merchant_aw_id])
    .on('error', function(err){
      console.log(err);
      // continue unzipping files, even if you encounter an error.  You can also remove these lines if you want the script to exit.
      if(merchants[++count]){
        downloadUnzipFile(merchants[count][merchant_aw_id]);
      }
    })
    .on('finish', function() {
      if(merchants[++count]){
        downloadUnzipFile(merchants[count][merchant_aw_id]);
      }
    });
};
```

Haven't tested, of course.  The main idea should work thought: call `downloadUnzipFile` recursively whenever the previous call errors out or finishes, as long as there are still items in the merchants array.

Comment: although, now that I reread your question, the error you were encountering has nothing to do with memory, but rather with trying to unzip a file that zlib doesn't support.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438855/error-incorrect-header-check-when-running-post .  You still will likely run into issues handling memory if you run your requests concurrently, though.