# Error: incorrect header check when running post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, zlib, fs

I need to get zip from rest call (for simulation I use postman with binary option for post and add a little zip file with folder and html file),during the simulation I want to get the data with express and extract the zip and put in some folder under C drive.
Currently when I run the following program(this is all the code which i've tried) but im getting error

> events.js:85
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>               ^ Error: incorrect header check
>       at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:366:17)

```
var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    zlib = require('zlib'),
    app = express();

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('C://myFolder', {flags: 'w'});
    req.pipe(zlib.createInflate()).pipe(writeStream);

});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log("Running on port" + 3000)
    }
)
```

in postman header i've added the following

```
content-Type ----> application/zip
```

How should I overcome this issue and save the zip ? **there is other recommended (zlib)library to get extract and save zip?**

Comment: I dont think postman can handle this. Did you try sending a curl request somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zlib` is meant to extract gzipped or deflated data, not .ZIP files.

You can use the [`node-unzip`](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip) module for those:

```
var unzip = require('unzip');
...
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var extractor = unzip.Extract({ path : 'C://myFolder' }).on('close', function() {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
  req.pipe(extractor);
});
```

If Postman can't handle uploads like this (as suggested in the comments), you can test using cURL:

```
$ curl -XPOST localhost:3000 --data-binary @test.zip
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working Voted up! Just one thing when I run it it takes about 10 sec until I got the response(file 3.5 MB size after extract)  can I make this process faster somehow?

Comment: @shopiaT there may be modules that provide faster unzipping, but I'm afraid I can't help you with any names (no experience with other modules myself). The code as shown is as simple as it's gonna get, not much room for speed improvement I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is sufficient!btw if I warp it on promise do you think that its better,im talking on the unzip.extract function...what do you think?

Comment: @shopiaT it won't matter, performance-wise. Also, `unzip.Extract()` is a stream function, which may be difficult to convert to a promise.