# Optimze post call to save performnace

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, express, unzip

I've Node application which is getting zip file from rest API request. I use the following code for file in size 2MB and it takes almost 10 sec , There is a way to improve performance here ?

The file should be extracted and saved in local system...

This codes works fine except the performance...

> `1. if the request should invoked from client and its take to long
>   when I should send the response? if I'll wait until the process
>   finish this can take 10 sec...
>
> 2.Should I use promise in this case if yes can you provide example please with the following code(blue bird,q...)
>
> 3.there is a way to optimize somehow the performance

```
 var unzip = require('unzip');
    app.post('/', function(req, res) {
        var ext = unzip.Extract({
            path: 'C://myFolder'
        }).on('close', function() {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }).on('error', function(err) {
            // res.sendStatus(500);
        });
        req.pipe(ext);
    });
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? POST a zipped file to a server, and extact this file on the fly?

Comment: @Tobi yeah, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31438855/893780) (different user but conspicuously similar)

Comment: I don't see where this question uses promises, Q or Bluebird?

Comment: Unzip the data on the client, send it unzipped over a zip-supporting protocol and you'll have the off-the-main-thread code in Node in C take care of it for you, it'll also make your life easier and mean this logic isn't in your code since it can be done at the HTTP level.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum- Thanks ,what does it mean "send it unzipped over a zip-supporting protocol and you'll have the off-the-main-thread code in Node",not sure that I got it...what is the unzip protocol you are talking about,I use postman express with node...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code isn't the problem, when I run the exact code it takes 750ms to extract a 7.5MB ZIP file. I used this to time it:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.time('unzip');
  var ext = unzip.Extract({ path: ... }).on('close', function() {
    console.timeEnd('unzip');
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }).on('error', function(err) {
    console.timeEnd('unzip');
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
  req.pipe(ext);
});
```

Uploading the file:

```
$ ls -al test.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 robert wheel 7553635 Jul 17 09:31 test.zip
$ curl -XPOST localhost:3012 --data-binary @test.zip
```

This is on a Macbook Pro.

You don't say how exactly you're timing the code, but my guess is that it takes 10 seconds between the client starting the upload to until it receives a response, which introduces a lot of extra variables (speed of upload, network connection, particular middleware in your Express app, etc).

Run the extraction code completely separate from Express to see if that really is the bottleneck. Here's a simple standalone script to test with:

```
var fs    = require('fs');
var unzip = require('unzip');

console.time('unzip');
fs.createReadStream('test.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path : ... })).on('close', function() {
  console.timeEnd('unzip');
});
```

If that takes 10 seconds for a 2MB file, I would think that your hardware is just wildly underpowered, which can't be solved from Node.js.

Comment: Thanks Robert 1+, my hardware is i5-4300 1.9 GHZ with 16GB ram,for two GB ram ,for example how much this take (2mb) in your hardware?

Comment: @JhonDree 7.5MB takes less than a second (i7 2.3Ghz, 16GB RAM). Your hardware specs don't suggest that the bottleneck is hardware.

Comment: did you try it with postman?I upload zip from binary and save it on my c drive...just it did you try the exact scenario ?

Comment: @JhonDree no, I don't use Postman, I use cURL. Please follow the instructions in my answer to time the actual ZIP extraction to rule out the problem is caused by that. If it's not, it's something else, but that's something you should investigate in another question probably.